# iphone dev - using an iPad to simulate an iPhone environment

Tags: iphone, ipad

I made a universal app and I need to test on iPhone and iPad devices. However, I only have an iPad now but not an iPhone. Is there an easy way to use an iPad to simulate an iPhone environment so that I can do testing on iPad (and pretend it is an iPhone)?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably build an iPhone only version of your app and run that on your iPad for testing.  Barring that you're probably stuck using the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think no. From my experience, you should at least, by borrow/ buy/ hire, have an iphone in latest phase of project like performance testing, because the performance is really different on simulator and on iphone

Comment: It's not just performance. The simulator is good, but not _perfect_. I have seen problems with code that works well in the simulator manifest problems on the device, and they may often be graphical glitches so very visible. Beg or borrow a device (or ad-hoc deploy to a willing friend)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no. However you can use the emulator that comes with the iPhone SDK to do your testing for iPhone devices - just set your Target to iPhone.

Comment: It's called a Simulator, not an Emulator, for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Or if it doesn't rely on any iPhone only facilities, an iPod Touch would be a cheaper option than buying an iPHone.

Comment: Yeah, I think the IPod Touch and Iphone can be considered similar. I am not sure, but in my company, we have both devices to test:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes NSArray is correct, it works.